# sql syntax error * FROM 'users' WHERE id = 10' at line 1

Tags: php, mysql

Okay so created a small form that pulls the id of the user from the database, I also created a function. I'm getting the error below. Can't seem to work out what I've done wrong. Thanks in advance.

This is the error:

> could not deleteYou have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual
>   that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to
>   use near '* FROM 'users' WHERE id = 12' at line 1

This is my function

```
 function  deleteUser(){
    global  $db;

    $id =  $_POST['id'];

  $query  = "DELETE * FROM 'users' ";
  $query  .="WHERE id = $id ";   
  $result =  mysqli_query($db, $query);

  if (!$result) {

      die ("could not delete" . mysqli_error($db));

  }   else {

      echo " user has been deleted";

     }   

}
```

This is the form

```
   <?php                

            require_once ("Includes/simplecms-config.php");
            require_once ("Includes/connectDB.php");
            include ("Includes/header.php");
            include ("functionsphp.php");

        if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

       deleteUser();

     }
     ?>

  <h1> Delete user details</h1>

  <form action="deleteUsers.php" method="post">

  <select name="id">

   <?php Showid() ?>

 </select>
 <p>Select the Id of the user to delete.</p>
 <br>

 <input type="submit" name="submit" value="DELETE">
```

Comment: `select * from `users` where id = '10'`  tried ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `*` from query

```
delete from user where id = $id
```

Is enough, your query should be like this

```
$query  = "
  DELETE 
    FROM users
   WHERE id = $id
 ";
```

Answer (score 1):

[SYNTAX](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/delete.html) is (remove the *)

```
delete from `users` where `id` = '$id';
```

or

```
delete from users where id = '$id';
```

1. QUOTES are used for string values.
2. BACKTICKS are used for identifiers names.

BACKTICKS(`) are only necessary when we use a reserved word as an identifier name.

EXAMPLE

123123e34 is a valid identifier name but is also an exponential number (we need backticks here).

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't show it in a comment.

Try changing:

```
DELETE * FROM 'users'
-------^------^-----^--- Change these single quotes to backticks
```

to

```
DELETE FROM `users`
```

Comment: heya,  so changing the single to back ticks, i now get this error, -   could not deleteCannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`big_mikes_electronics`.`users_in_roles`, CONSTRAINT `users_in_roles_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`))

Comment: You need to delete the dependent foreign key relations first then delete from parent table.

Comment: thanks very much, all is resolved now, not with a lack of swearing at the laptop. haha.